# Log4j with Springboot not appending/creating file

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

My logger is printing out logs to my console, but I want it to append my `.log` file. I placed the following poperties inside my application.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout, stderr, dailyfile

log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p %m (%C::%M:%L)%n

log4j.appender.stderr.Threshold = ERROR
log4j.appender.stderr = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p %m (%C::%M:%L)%n

log4j.appender.dailyfile.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.appender.dailyfile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dailyfile.File = ../webapps/test/a.log
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p {%t} %m (%C::%M:%L)%n

log4j.appender.dailyfile.DatePattern ='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

And I have a few `log.info()` calls in my code:

```
log.info("bla bla bla bla");
```

For now my logs are visible on the console. This code can't create a file somehow. Even if I create the file manually, it is not being updated (appended). What should I do in order for my code to work?

Comment: Post your folder structure

Comment: /media/user/Data/Projects/Learn/demo is my project catalog and here I would like to store my log folder with log files inside. Using path from my example (webapp/...) should create  webapp/test/a.log inside my current (project) folder. Am I right?

Comment: Property file locate in which folder?

Comment: /media/user/Data/Projects/Learn/demo/src/main/resources

Comment: log4j.appender.dailyfile.File =a.log use this and check whether the file created under demo

Comment: Nope, nothing has changed. Still got log on console but not in a file.

Comment: Place ur log4j.properties file in the following: WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know, that file with Log4j properties has to be named exactly `log4j.properties`. In my case all I had to do was create file, place all properties inside and move this file to src/resources. Thanks for help guys!